# Cant resolve Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.*.ExposedDropdownMenu

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android

I tried to create a `AutoCompleteTextView`, surrounded by a `TextInputLayout`. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Menu.md#exposed-dropdown-menus), I should use this style:

```
Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.*.ExposedDropdownMenu
```

But I can't resolve this style. Android Studio says I can only use:

```
@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense
@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox
@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense
@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox
```

My project uses

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

The final result should look like this:

```java
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text">

  <AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: You should use `com.google.android.material:material` material library instead of support design `com.android.support:design`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede I am using '`com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`' in my project, yet getting the same error. It appears that the documentation refers to components in 1.0.1-alpha, without clearly mentioning it.

Comment: Yes, it means that it's added in version `1.0.1-alpha`. Update your dependencies though and check again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I raised this query in Android Material Components' Github issues.

Based on [this response](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/402#issuecomment-502812796), the public documentation is based not on the current stable release, but on the latest alpha (or beta) release. There is no way to tell from the documentation on material.io about which components are in stable, alpha or beta versions of the library.

Having clarified that, the solution to this issue is to upgrade your support-design library, as suggested by @jeel-vankhede, to:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
```

---

Related heads up, in case you are also using ViewModels (lib v. 2.0.0):

Upgrading to 1.1.0-alpha of Material design library automatically updates the androidx.lifecycle libraries to 2.1.0+. This update has a breaking change from 2.0.0 which may break your view model code. This change is only observed in minified versions of the app.

Comment: Please also note that the library also requires AndroidX and that the OP must update his project to AndroidX before he can include that dependency. (Note: Android Studio can do this with `Refactor` > `Migrate to AndroidX…` which should migrate all dependencies to AndroidX, as well as the support design library to the new Material Components library)

Comment: As mentioned by @R3mx, don't forget to update the app theme `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Comment: I'm using 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0' and the problem is still present :-(

Answer (score 6):

And don't forget to use Theme.MaterialComponents in your application

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    ...
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1141), the `*` in the documentation means to using any style from `TextInputLayout`, such as `FilledBox` or `OutlinedBox`.
Moreover, it is not yet available in the 1.1.0 version, so I successfully made it work using this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
```

and any of these two styles (remember to use Theme.MaterialComponents in your application, as @R3mx mentioned):

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
```

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
```

Comment: i just removed * with FilledBox and it works, thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can now use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

Answer (score 0):

In this `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.*.ExposedDropdownMenu"`

> Here (*) mean `OutlinedBox` or `FilledBox`

Use latest Dependencies of `Material`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

Also Check You are using Material Theme if not then make with [Material 3 Builder](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder#/custom) : make you custom `theme` and `Export`. Then open and copy paste in `theme` and `color` in Your project.
Also check `AndroidManifest.xml` for updated theme `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`.

Image Result in `OutLinedBox`

[image: State filled is Example]

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:hint="State">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/edittextState"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Happy Coding:)